# Why does css define my text two different ways in the same div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this html:

```
<div class="lasvegas">
Events <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
class="findanevent"><font size="3">Find an Event</font>. 
</div></a> <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">. 
<div class="postanevent"><font size="3">Post an 
Event</font></div></a>
```

The first piece of text, `events` displays how I want it, the second `Find An Event` and `Post An Event` displays the text in black. I want all text to display as `Events` does. Page ref- https://adsler.co.uk/events/. The word `events`is neon glow with pink.

I have this css controlling it.

```
 @import, url(//fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=
 Pacifico);
 body {
 min-height:100vh;
 padding-top:5rem;
 background:
 #112
 url(//images.weserv.nl/url=i.imgur.com/6QJjYMe.jpg)
 center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.lasvegas {
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
font-size:80px;
border: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
text-align:
center;
text-shadow: 1px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px
#ff00de,  0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de;
}
.lasvegas
span {
animation: blink .3s infinite alternate;
}
.lasvegas
span.delay {
animation-duration:6s;
animation-delay: 2s
animation-direction: alternate
cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3,
1.0)
}

@keyframes blink {
0%  {
}

50% {
}

60% {
text-shadow:0 0
2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .
4); text-stroke: 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

70% {
text-
shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px.
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px
#ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de,  0 0 100px #ff00de;
}

80% {
text-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
text-stroke: 2px
rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

100% {
text-shadow: 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,1),0
0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0
100px #ff00de;
}

}
```

As I understand, if its within the same div, it should be governed by the same css?

If I close the div, like so:

```
<div class="lasvegas">
Events </div>
```

and:

```
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
class="findanevent"><font size="3">Find an Event</font>. 
</div></a> <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">. 
<div class="postanevent"><font size="3">Post an 
Event</font></div></a>
```

The second two bits of text disappear entirely from the page.

Comment: the font tag is obsolete and should not be used.  If you want your anchors to display like normal text, you need to add specific styles for them as they are rendered differently to normal text by browsers - see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_links

Comment: Ok. How? Please see updated question.

Comment: Read the link I have added to the above comment

Comment: Ok. Tried:`.findanevent:visited {display: inline-block; font-family: helvetica;color: white! Important; margin-top:50px;} ` didn't want to work to change color

Comment: your class is on the div inside the anchor, you need to style the anchor, besides you still need to remove the font tag.  Try this: https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-styling-links-like-boss/

Comment: Ok but trying:  `a:visited` will also style all the other a:visited links when i just want to target`.findanevent` and`.postanevent`Font i can deal with later.

Comment: so give those links a class and target them.  this is all very basic stuff, perhaps you should do a tutorial and learn how to do it properly rather than asking millions of questions

Comment: I don't understand, they have a class, namely-`. findanevent`and`.postanevent`

Comment: No, your divs inside your anchors have a class

Comment: Yes......... .?

Comment: Ah, like.... `<div class="eventslinks"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
class="findanevent"><font size="3">Find an Event</font>. 
</div></a> <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">. 
<div class="postanevent"><font size="3">Post an 
Event</font></div></a></div>`??? then`. eventslinks: visited {foobar}`???

Comment: I'm right aren't I? :-) my genius comes naturally :-)

Comment: Didn't work..... :-(

Comment: Would you mind explaining? I'm just not as clever as you in these things....

Answer (score 0):

I found that in your css:
(so-css-shapely.css)

```
* {
  color: #000000;
}}
```

That's why it's black.

Comment: Ok. So how to change to pink?

Comment: Open that css and modify the value for *. Change #000000; to pink; or in HEX #FFC0CB;

Comment: Will that change other things on the site too?